# how to add fixed tags to textarea in tinymce and phpBB forum?

Tags: tags, tinymce, textarea, fixed, phpbb

i have a phpBB forum , and i want to add tinymce with rtl support to it.
i have successfully integrated tinymce to it using this post : 
https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?p=6955695

then activated html tag support for the forum using this mod : ( i know possible dangers ) 
http://nmguse.webfactional.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=535

it has permissions for both topics and users / groups for allowing usage of html.
but when i allow an admin/forum for using html , that mod requires usage of [html] and [/html] 
tags .

i want to automate this , so that the users/admins don't need to enter that [html] tags.

i have searched for hours , played with tinymce plugins , and at last found that the following html code is coming from tiny_mce.js it self and not the rtl/ltr direction plugin.
the addition of

or   tags are froum tiny_mce.js itself.

also i couldn't understand the usage of setcontent in tinymce

tinymce3 adds this code when i align right or use rtl , and when i submit the data to forum , it shows the html codes if i don't use [html] tag.

```
<div style="text-align: right;" dir="rtl">
```

i wanted to change tinymce to add [html][/html] , which i wasn't successful , and then i tried adding the tags to the textarea as default text.
now the problem is that still tinymce adds some div before the default text when i submit the data. so some html raw codes are displayed , then some html are fine , and some raw code renders again.

at line 144 of posting_editor.html from phpBB version 3.0.11 :

```
    <div id="message-box">
    <textarea class="rich" 
    <!-- IF S_UCP_ACTION and not S_PRIVMSGS and not S_EDIT_DRAFT -->name="signature" id="signature" style="height: 9em;"
    <!-- ELSE -->name="message" id="message"<!-- ENDIF -->
    rows="15" cols="76" tabindex="4" onselect="storeCaret(this);" 
    onclick="storeCaret(this);" onkeyup="storeCaret(this);" onfocus="initInsertions();" class="inputbox">**[html]**{MESSAGE}{DRAFT_MESSAGE}{SIGNATURE}**[/html]**
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: here is the picture : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76259504/phpBB3/phpBB-tinymce-problem.jpg

any suggestions for automatically adding [help] [/help] once , at the end of textarea when submitting data?